# google api v3 key works locally (dev) but not in production

Tags: google-maps-api-3, api-key

I'm trying to use Google Places Autocomplete API in my site, but when i submit the url (in this case, via cURL on php), the page returns no results (completely blank page). But it happens only when i call the page from my web hosting; the localhost dev application works fine. If I paste the url below in the browser, it works fine too.
My php test page has something like this:

```
    function curl_file($url, $timeout=0){
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
        //curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout );
        $str = curl_exec( $ch );
        curl_close( $ch );
        return $str;
    } 

    $content = curl_file("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=flamboyant&location=-16.698053,-49.268947&radius=20000&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyBzdiVqEIh2CXBm3gNUsvWdIl1Z-NvW298");
    echo $content;
```

The variable **content** should echo the same JSON response as in the browser but the page displays absolutely blank.
Could someone help me about this?

p.s.: my google api key are set to “Any referer allowed”. I tried to put on Rerefers the URL site *.imoveisgo.com/* but doesnt work too.

thanks all!!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is SSL problem of cURL. Please try this code:

```
function curl_file($url, $timeout=0){
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
  //curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout );
  $str = curl_exec( $ch );
  if(curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo "Err#".curl_error($ch);
    echo curl_error($ch);
  }
  curl_close( $ch );
  return $str;
} 

$content = curl_file("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=flamboyant&location=-16.698053,-49.268947&radius=20000&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyBzdiVqEIh2CXBm3gNUsvWdIl1Z-NvW298");
echo $content;
```

Comment: i didn't know about this SSL problem. Using the code, i could see some error in certificate validation.

Comment: i didn't know about this SSL problem. Using the code, i could see some error in certificate validation. i found a code that ignore this verification.
`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);`
Thansk a lot!!!